# Database of unique attributes of biological model systems

Tags: genetics, phylogenetics, animal-models, resource-recommendation

I am interested in deviations from standard eukaryotic biological mechanisms:

- Sperm chromatin lacks nucleosomes, and are instead *highly* condensed by protamines. (most eukaryotic chromatin has chromatin with nucleosomes).
- Camelid and cartilaginous fish antibodies are single-domain (most vertebrates have heavy chain + light chain antibodies).
- Drosophila homologous chromosomes undergo [transvection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transvection_(genetics)) and are tightly paired. (Transvection is not usually observed in eukaryotes.)

These are some of the unique peculiarities I've found among model systems that deviate from "expected" biology. Is there a running database that catalogues unique attributes of different model systems? If not for trivia, I find them extremely inspiring for mechanistic studies!

Comment: I find this to be a very interesting question, but I think that it's critically important for you to be clear about 2 things: 1) what is the taxonomic level of focus? 2) for any given taxonomic level, what is the "expected" biology that is deviated from? I have edited to try to reflect this better.

Comment: No database that I've heard about. But you can add [achiasmy](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4949207/) to your list (absence of homologous recombination in some drosophilid and lepidopteran males). I've always found that intriguing and sometimes a useful exploit for genetic crossings.